# I want to add functionality of autocomplete using angularjs,mysql and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, angularjs

hey i am working on a project which uses angularjs, mysql, php and Jquery. I want to add autocomplete on a text box where when i entered a word it will suggest the rest of words from database. Can anyone send me the code for this

**with HTML code**

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: i tried in jquery and that works but i want code in angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that might be able to help:

```
 <form action="demo_form.asp" autocomplete="on">
   First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
   Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
   E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
   <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: Bro its not that auto complete which you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

Check Angular UI project, you should use [typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) directive.

An example from Angular UI page:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

**Controller**

```
  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
```

Or take a look at this example: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/VB43wxoDBhVyRMnKUHr9?p=preview

Comment: bro i want to get suggestions from my database

Comment: Yes, you can replace the array `$scope.states` with a call to your backend.